# WordPress Cumulus

Tags: plugins

How to install WP-cumulus add-on into WordPress ?

Thanks,

Comment: What seems to be the issue with installing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there you go: [**Installing wp-cumulus**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-cumulus/installation/)